# Find why npm dedupe hangs infinitely

Tags: npm

I'm trying to flatten my dependency tree. When I'm using command

```
npm dedupe
```

It just hangs eating processor and even after half an hour it does not respond...

When I execute `npm -ddd dedupe` to see what is happening (`-ddd` sets loglevel to silly level most verbosive possible)

I see that it hangs after building ideal tree:

```
npm sill idealTree ├─┬ yargs-parser@5.0.0-security.0
npm sill idealTree │ └── camelcase@3.0.0
npm sill idealTree ├─┬ yargs@7.1.1
npm sill idealTree │ └── camelcase@3.0.0
npm sill idealTree └── yup@0.31.0
npm sill dedupe generateActionsToTake
```

And it hangs on `npm sill dedupe generateActionsToTake`.

What can be reason of this? `npm doctor` says this:

```
Check                               Value                        Recommendation
npm ping                            ok
npm -v                              v6.14.9
node -v                             v14.15.1
npm config get registry             https://registry.npmjs.org/
which git                           /usr/bin/git
Perms check on cached files         ok
Perms check on global node_modules  ok
Perms check on local node_modules   ok
Verify cache contents               verified 10269 tarballs
```

I don't know what else should I check. I noticed also that this is happening only in one of my project.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?